# Exporting Sentinel-2A imagery from QGIS to ERDAS Imagine 2013

Tags: qgis, erdas-imagine, sentinel-2

I have downloaded a Sentinel-2 image and loaded the 10m bands from the .xml file in QGIS which works fine. I simply want to open the image in Erdas Imagine for use in accuracy assessment in a true colour composite.

In QGIS the bands are as follows: Band 1 (red) 2 (green) 3 (blue) which looks fine.

[image: Image in QGIS]

I then right clicked > saved as a GeoTIFF and opened in Erdas, however when I use the same band combination the colours looks different, as below.

[image]

Does anyone know a solution to display the image as seen in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

It all comes down to histogram stretching options you use in QGIS and ERDAS.

First, you should check your stretching in QGIS:

Right click your layer > Properties > Style and check if Stretch enhancement is set. 
For example, a very common stretching method is Min-Max. 
Here is how to set it manually:

[image]

Then, if you are happy with what your image looks like you can use the same (or any other) stretching method in ERDAS:
After you open an image, go to "Multispectral" tab, click "Adjust Radiometry" and select "Min-Max" from Standard Stretches.

After this, your image should look identical both in QGIS and ERDAS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Performed a Linear contrast stretch and it has improved significantly, although if anyone has any other answers please post.

Thanks